# Should I put a Semicolon (;) when I use onclick=""

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, onclick

Should I put a Semicolon (`;`) when I use `onclick=""`?

```
<p onclick="closeLightBox();">Click<p>
```

or:

```
<p onclick="closeLightBox()">Click<p>
```

Comment: You should generally avoid the onclick attribute. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: @David: I'd stick with the attribute for trivial applications. I really don't agree with the current received wisdom that event handler attributes are inherently evil and to be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The semicolon in this position, is valid, but not mandatory.

Answer (score 16):

It is good practice to include it, since if you decide to add other statements after the call, it is clear and easy to do so.  However, the code will run either way.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer a semicolon.  I know it is optional (as it is many times in JS), but I like to be uniform and it helps to alert the person that the statement is complete.

Answer (score 6):

As an optional semicolon, it's a matter of taste.