# Calling multiple functions that reference (theID)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am a beginner at HTML, and was wondering if it is possible to do what I am trying to do below. It is crashing, but I'm not sure if the only reason is my syntax, or if it is not possible at all.

The declaration of the function:

```
<!-- Copyright 2005, Sandeep Gangadharan -->
<!-- For more free scripts go to http://www.sivamdesign.com/scripts/ -->

if (document.getElementById) {
document.writeln('<style type="text/css"><!--')
document.writeln('.texter {display:none} @media print {.texter {display:block;}}')
document.writeln('//--></style>') }

function close(theID) {
if (document.getElementById(theID).style.display == "block") { document.getElementById(theID).style.display = "none" } }

function open(theID) {
if (document.getElementById(theID).style.display == "block") { document.getElementById(theID).style.display = "none" }
else { document.getElementById(theID).style.display = "block" } }

// -->

</script>
</head>
```

Use of the function:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" rowspan="0">
<div>•&nbsp;<a href="/tallwalls/" target="_blank"><b>Tall Walls Sizer</b></a></div>
<p onClick="open('a4'), close('a1','a2','a3')" style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer">       
<span style="color: #808080;">[Click here for more information]</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="a4" class="texter">
<td style="padding:0px;width:210px;"><a href="/tallwalls/" target="_blank" title="Tall Walls Sizer"><img src="/images/logos/tallWALLS.gif" alt="" width="206" height="41"/></a></td>
<td>
<div>DESCRIPTION</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Mainly the **onClick="open('a4'), close('a1','a2','a3')"** is where I am not sure if this is proper syntax.

---

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention, that the other ids do exist. They are composed of this same pattern x4

---

Thanks in advance,

SirKaydian

Comment: They need to be separated by a semicolon. It's just like anywhere else in JS. Statements should end in semicolon. You only have one parameter for `close()` but you're passing in 3 things. Won't crash, but you won't have anything to access a2 or a3

Comment: So would I say: close('a1'); close(a2); close(a3)? along those lines?

Comment: That would work. Or you could pass an array and iterate over the array in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript lines end in ; so you need to first use `open('a4');`

Also, you have only defined close() for one argument, so you need to split `close('a1','a2','a3')` into `close('a1'); close('a2'); close('a3');`

If you're new to HTML I would suggest a little bit of reading on jQuery. Its hide() and show() methods will make what you are trying to do very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - you need to use semicolons to separate the function calls. See [related SO post regarding usage of semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4962916/175679).

```
<p onClick="open('a4');close('a1');close('a2');close('a3'); return false;"/>
```

Comment: `close()` takes only one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider your method close(theID):

```
function close(theID) {
if (document.getElementById(theID).style.display == "block") { document.getElementById(theID).style.display = "none" } }
```

This function accepts only one arguments and you are trying to apply close on multiple arguments. In this case the code would look like

```
function close(){
   if(arguments.length > 0 ){
     for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        closeMe(arguments[i]);
     }
   }
}

function closeMe(id){
 if (document.getElementById(theID).style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById(theID).style.display = "none" 
 } 
}
```

Similarly your open function.

You have serious issues with your onClick handler

onClick="open('a4'), close('a1','a2','a3')"

should be

```
onClick ="open('a4'); close('a1', 'a2', 'a3');"
```